# Higher age or older age?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, science

Which of the forms is correct: *patients were of higher age* or *older age*?

Could both forms be used?

I am asking for a formal use in medical scientific journals.

The most suited form here would probably be *patients were older*, but the question is if other forms are also acceptable.

Comment: You would not normally say **either** "higher/lower age" or "older/younger age" - you'd simply say "older" or "younger", or "the same age".

Comment: As noted, *older* is preferred, but if you want a phrase that includes *age*, then we usually use *greater age*.

Comment: Billions of people have died of old age. Not a single person has ever died of a high one.

Comment: the aged, the elderly, old-aged, etc. should work?

Comment: *Which of the forms is correct: patients were of higher age or older age?* - without a full sentence and some context, the question cannot be answered. (On the face of it, "age" requires the indefinite article.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP asks which form is correct, not which is most common. So I wanted to give some references from a scholarly text.

A search in all quotations from the electronic version of the Oxford English Dictionary (Second Edition, 1989) of "older/greater/higher age" yields four instances of "greater age", one of "older age", and one of "higher age" (but in the expression "higher age-groups").

- The complete quotation with "higher age" is this:

> All show, under natural conditions, the expected ‘population pyramid’, formed by large numbers of young individuals and gradually decreasing numbers of individuals of the higher age-groups.

It seems to me that "higher" refers here to the position of some age-groups within this conceptual pyramid; it isn't qualifying "age", and doesn't mean "older".

- The quotation with "older age" is this, from 1869:

> The woman is of an older age than in other described cases [of scleroderma].

This is an example very similar to yours. *Personally* I consider it acceptable usage since it's quoted by the OED.

- Three quotations with "greater age" use this expression in the sense of "older". I also want to emphasize that they date 1865–1880. However, "greater age" also appears in the definition of "older":

> 1. In the ordinary senses of *old*: Of greater age; that has lived or existed longer, of longer existence or standing; more ancient.

Thus it seems to me that "of greater age" is also a completely legitimate expression.

The scarcity and the dates of all these quotations seem to indicate that the two expressions that seem legitimate are nevertheless rarely used.

That said, the final judgement is yours and depends on your personal views about language and standards.

Here's a snapshot of the search results

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate your contribution, though six samples may not form a large enough set. Please consider using a larger corpus, e.g. [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca) or [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha).

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to add an answer that references a scholarly text, because the other answers reference google or give no reference at all. The OP was asking which form is correct, not which is most used.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is not explicit. I understand that all these references indicate all three forms are correct. Is that so? If yes, that would be good to indicate it in the answer. And If this is obvious to you guys - then excuse me, I come from the medical field.

Answer (score 3):

"Of older age" is chiefly an [Americanism/ of newer usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20greater%20age%2Cof%20higher%20age%2Cof%20older%20age&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20greater%20age%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20higher%20age%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20older%20age%3B%2Cc0). (Opinion:) `I would think it's obviously incorrect, though, much like "at *faster speed" and such.`

Otherwise, it has mostly (and appropriately) been "[of greater age](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20greater%20age%2Cof%20higher%20age%2Cof%20older%20age&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20greater%20age%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20higher%20age%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20older%20age%3B%2Cc0)," (opinion:) `which I would recommend singularly` — sadly, it's now losing to the *older* alternative everywhere.

Though "of higher age" is in use, especially in certain contexts, it's not the preferred phrase.

Comment: Where's English heading, see the nGrams cited. Use discretion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is common to say **either** *higher age* or *older age*. People normally say (in your case):

> *older/younger patients*

Or *patients of the same age*, just like what Max said in the comment above.

But I also think it is grammatically correct to use *patients of higher age* or *of older age* (it's just not preferable to use).
Apparently though, based on [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=higher%20age,older%20age), the phrase *older age* is more popular than *higher age*.

*Older age* is quite popular in the UK, US, Australia, India, Canada and South Africa. Whilst *higher age* is merely used in the UK, US and India.

Therefore, my conclusion is:

> ***older patients*** is better to use than ***patients of older age*** than ***patients of higher age***.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could say:

*The results are dated `_______` and  patients **who were born before `_______`** showed [...].*

Here is a example from :
https://www.sss.gov/Registration/Men-Born-Before-1960

> NOTE: Men born from March 29, 1957 through December 31, 1959, were not required to register with the Selective Service System because the registration program was suspended when they would have reached age 18. The requirement to register with Selective Service was reinstated in 1980, but only **for men born January 1, 1960, or later**.